# Run Apache Derby as windows service

Tags: java, windows-services, derby

I am using apache derby in our project. Every time,I have to manually start server of derby, i.e. run startnetworkserver.bat . Is is possible to install it as a windows web service? And I would also want to add the service in windows startup list. So that each time I start the system, it will automatically get started.So,I dont have to manually start server.
I am using apache tomcat as windows service. I want to do same for derby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [JavaServiceWrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html), which is a widely-used, well-documented wrapper to make Java programs run as a Windows service.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [Apache Procrun](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/procrun.html). Its a Windows executable, that allows you to install / uninstall java programs as Windows services.

Installation of the service goes as follows (from the project site):

```
prunsrv //IS//TestService --DisplayName="Test Service" \
    --Install=prunsrv.exe --Jvm=auto --StartMode=jvm --StopMode=jvm \
    --StartClass=org.apache.SomeStartClass --StartParams=arg1;arg2;arg3 \
    --StopClass=org.apache.SomeStopClass --StopParams=arg1#arg2
```

After that, you just start/stop the service using:

```
net start TestService
net stop TestService
```

or using Services view from My Computer.

Oh, and it's free! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I was in the same problem and try with a wide variety of tools and wrappers to get Derby as a windows service, among them all the ways depicted in Derby wiki (http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/DerbyWindowsService).

Anyway, none of these tools worked for me except for procrun tools as provided by Appache foundation, which is used in tomcat to get this server as a windows server. So, following next steps:

1. Get the two key files of procrun (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/binaries.html):

   - **prunsrv.exe** - service application for running applications as services.
   - **prunmgr.exe** - the GUI manager application used to monitor and configure installed services.
2. Copy these files at Derby/bin (supposing you have a folder named Derby which is the DERBY_HOME).
3. To following the procrun convention, rename these files to derby.exe and derbyw.exe. If you want to use different names you can but you should then adapt the attached script.
4. To create the service at windows you have to execute the next script. It was writen to be executed on up-level folder (..) of Derby folder, and by using a portable version of java 32 bits.

   - **NOTE:** I've split it on different lines, but it has to be executed in only one line

   > Derby\bin\derby.exe //IS//DerbyService
   >   --DisplayName="Derby Service"
   >   --Description="This is a Derby databse server"
   >   --Install="%cd%\Derby\bin\derby.exe" --Startup=auto
   >   --JavaHome "**%cd%\Java_32_portable**"
   >   --Jvm="**%cd%\Java_32_portable\bin\client\jvm.dll**"
   >   --StartMode=Java --StopMode=Java
   >   --StartClass=org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl --StartParams=start
   >   --StopClass=org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl --StopParams=shutdown
   >   --Classpath="%cd%\Derby\lib\derby.jar;%cd%\Derby\lib\derbyrun.jar;%cd%\Derby\lib\derbynet.jar;%cd%\Derby\lib\derbytools.jar"
   >   ++JvmOptions="**-Dderby.system.home=%cd%\Derby;-Dderby.install.url=%cd%\Derby\lib;-Dderby.authentication.provider=BUILTIN;-Dderby.storage.pageCacheSize=8000;-Dderby.storage.pageSize=20000;-Dderby.database.sqlAuthorization=false**"
5. IMPORTANT. You should adapt bold parts.

   - Set your JAVA_HOME variable and your jvm.dll appropriately
   - Set your own Derby specific parameters within ++JvmOptions separated by ';'. For example, add user-pasword autentication with:
     -Dderby.database.sqlAuthorization=true;-Dderby.user."user-name"=password
6. Finally, you can check your service starts well with

   > `net start DerbyService`

**Advice:** you can put all toghether in a bat file as I have, where you can define previously JAVA_HOME or any other necessary variable.

Answer (score 0):

Look Into winsw which is what Glassfish uses.  Requires .NET.

Comment: Glassfish is a rather big Java project.

Answer (score 0):

It is a long time since the original question, anyway I want to confirm that I properly set a Derby Service in my Windows 64 bits using the instructions provided by @Richard P. My script finished slightly different as follow:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\java\jdk1.8.0_25
set DERBY_INSTALL=C:\tools\db-derby-10.13.1.1-bin

%DERBY_INSTALL%\bin\derby.exe //IS//DerbyService --DisplayName="My Derby Service" --Description="My Derby Database Engine Service" --Install="%DERBY_INSTALL%\bin\derby.exe" --Startup=auto --JavaHome "%JAVA_HOME%" --Jvm="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\client\jvm.dll" --StartMode=Java --StopMode=Java --StartClass=org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl --StartParams=start --StopClass=org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl --StopParams=shutdown --Classpath="%DERBY_INSTALL%\lib\derby.jar;%DERBY_INSTALL%\lib\derbyrun.jar;%DERBY_INSTALL%\lib\derbynet.jar;%DERBY_INSTALL%\lib\derbytools.jar" ++JvmOptions="-Dderby.system.home=%DERBY_INSTALL%;-Dderby.install.url=%DERBY_INSTALL%\lib;-Dderby.authentication.provider=BUILTIN;-Dderby.storage.pageCacheSize=8000;-Dderby.storage.pageSize=20000;-Dderby.database.sqlAuthorization=false"
```